# firebaseAuth does not respond in AngularJS for Authentication (login and register)

Tags: angularjs, authentication, firebase

I am trying to use firebaseAuth for user authentication for login and registration on my web app, but I have no idea why the register and the login button does not respond. Given that I'm still on the learning curve of using firebase, this may not be quite surprising. So I have the following AuthService and AuthController code:

**AuthService:**

```
angular.module('directiveAngularApp')
.service('Auth', function($firebaseAuth, FIREBASE_URL, $rootScope) {
    var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL+'/users');
    var auth = $firebaseAuth(ref);

    var Auth = {
      register: function (user) {
        return auth.$createUser(user.email, user.password, function(error) {
            if (error === null) {
              console.log('user created successfully')
            } else {
              console.log('error in creating users: ' + error);
            }
        });
      }, //register

      login: function (user) {
        return auth.$authWithPassword({
            email: user.email,
            password: user.password},
          function(error, userData){
            if (error) {
              console.log('login failed');
            } else {
              console.log('Authentication successful: ' + userData);
            }
        });
      }, //login

      logout: function () {
        auth.$logout();
      }
    };

    return Auth;
  });
```

**AuthController:**

```
angular.module('directiveAngularApp')
.controller('AuthCtrl', function($scope, $location, Auth){
    $scope.login = function() {
      console.log('in the login function');
      Auth.login($scope.user).then(function() {
        console.log('in the promise after login');
        $location.path('/');
      })
    };

    $scope.register = function() {
      Auth.register($scope.user).then(function() {
        return Auth.login($scope.user).then(function() {
          console.log('promise called: register successful');
          $location.path('/');
        });
      });
    };

  });
```

In the web form, I have the following two fields that are set to be ng-models:

```
ng-model="user.email"
ng-model="user.password"
```

The **Login** button is linked the login() function and the **Register** button is linked to the register() function in the above `AuthController`. However, when I click on either Login or Register button, there's not a response.

Answer (score 0):

CreateUser takes an object as a parameter with the new API

auth.$createUser(user);

https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/createuser.html